# Названия видов ограждения и крепления

Tags: лексика

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какое название имеют эта перегородка в туалетной комнате и крепление, которым она пригвождена к стене?

Answer (score 1):

Такие небольшие перегородки, как на фотографии, так и называются — [**писсуарные перегородки**](http://luxal.ru/katalog-produkcii/pissuarnye-peregorodki-iz-plastika), а металлический элемент (крепление) — это **уголок**.

Перегородки могут быть выполнены из пластика, ДСП, закаленного тонированного стекла; иногда их ещё называют *навесная стена* или [*ширма сантехническая*](http://luxal.ru/product-category/pissuarnye-peregorodki).